# Получение почты с POP3

Tags: c#, email, pop3

Использую для получения и прочтении почты вот эту библиотеку `using OpenPop.Pop3`, подскажите пожалуйста способы, как понять, что сообщение еще не прочитано? Или единственный вариант это прочитать все что уже есть на сервере, у себя в ПО поставить флаг им прочитано, и при следующем обращении сверять то что я уже загрузил и то что поступило?

Comment: У pop3 есть две опции "оставлять на сервере" и "удалять с сервера". В зависимости от потребностей возможны два варианта работы. В том же The bat - для pop3 есть две опции. Что б обойти эту проблему - используют более новые протоколы imap4 и... ещё есть SOAP-протокол для почты (MS-Exchange Server).